# objective-c linker error with OAuth2 library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

I'm getting this error when I try to build my project in Xcode:

> ld: library not found for -lGTMOAuth2 clang: 
>   error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And we're using pods, so I opened the workspace, not the project.

I just got Xcode version 8.3.3, so not sure if this is causing any errors...

Comment: Show your pod file.

Comment: Attach screenshot or text from the Xcode build log with expanded linker error entry.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out OAuth2 was not included in the Pod File, and I didn't check because I thought it was there before I pulled the latest version of the app. Thanks John Tracid.